# Qt5 use Sqlite Database Select sum()

Tags: sqlite, select, sum, qt5

when I try to select with QSqlQuery:

```
select mwst, sum(in), sum(out) from costs group by mwst
```

I got the error: QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

In SQLite Database Browser tool the select runs without error.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please show the code where you execute that.

Comment: mwst_query.prepare("select mwst, sum(`ein`), sum(`aus`) from kasse group by mwst");

Comment: The part where you iterate over the result may be the error.

Comment: no, i think not, when i take "select mwst, sum(in) from kasse group by mwst" it runs without error, only when i take two sum()'s in the query -> error

Comment: sorry, I was too hasty!! The error is in the code when I iterate over the result. Thanks for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 0):

have you used `bool QSqlQuery::next()` to set the query on a valid value (if the query succeeded, you should get results

like:

```
QSqlQuery qry("select * from table");
while (qry.next())
{
    qDebug() << qry.value(0).toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes I have, the problem is solved , I have a error in my code when I iterate over the result. See the comment above from juergen d. Thank you!